# MySql trigger, update another table on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I've already, searched and read, many answers about this issue , but couldn't get a clear answer on how to do this.

My query is the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Stock_Update` AFTER INSERT ON `Store_db`.`Product_Supply` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `Store_db`.`Stock` AS `ST`
    SET `ST`.`Stock_Quantity` = `ST`.`Stock_Quantity` + `Product_Supply`.`Supply_Quantity`
    WHERE `ST`.`Product_ID` = `Product_Supply`.`Product_ID`;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks In Advance.

P.S. A More Generic Answer would be nice too and might be helpful for others as well

Comment: A quick description of the error you are getting would have been helpful.

Comment: I was getting that it couldnt find the columns that you later told me to replace with NEW.ColumnName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within a trigger on a given table, all references to fields of this table must be prefixed by either `NEW.` or `OLD.`, which refers respectively to the value of this field after or before the change.

In your case, you probably want to add the newly inserted quantity to your existing stock: use `NEW.Supply_Quantity` (do not mention `Product_Supply`, this is already implied by the `NEW` keyword).

Likewise, you certainly want to use `NEW.Product_ID` in your condition.

Notice that `NEW` is not available in a trigger on deletion, like `OLD` in a trigger on insertion.